# Can't accept $null

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a AD user in my OU called public that has a username of numbers is enabled and a password set that is password1. When I run the command I get the error A positional Parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$null'.

Any help would be appreciated

Here is what I put into powershell

```
`New-ADUser -Name "BoB Glen" -GivenName "BoB"-Surname "Glen" -DisplayName "2003487" $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "pa$$word1" -AsPlainText -Force -AccountPassword $secpsswd -Enabled $true -Path "OU=Public,DC=Company,DC=epl,DC=local"`
```

Here is the entire error

```
New-ADUser : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$null'.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-ADUser -Name "Adam Bandola" -GivenName "Adam" -Surname "Bandola"  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so lets break apart whats happening :

```
New-ADUser -Name "BoB Glen" -GivenName "BoB"-Surname "Glen" 
    -DisplayName "2003487" $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString 
    -String "pa$$word1" -AsPlainText -Force -AccountPassword $secpsswd 
    -Enabled $true -Path "OU=Public,DC=Company,DC=epl,DC=local"
```

The symbol ` is a escape character in powershell. An example of how to use it would be :

```
write-output " `" "
```

this would output : **"** instead of the and error : **missing the terminator** which would be thrown is I did " " ". you can also use it to split long commands into multiable lines like

```
Get-Alias`
-name "%"
```

In the Command you are trying to use a **-whatever** is a parameter and the very next thing after it as the value you are submitting to that parameter

```
-parameter Value
```

Also in powershell the **$** is a variable.

```
$Hello = "World"
```

The current issue you are having is you are calling a command and then try to create a variable in the middle of the command, as well as starting the command with a escape key and ending it with a escape key (unless its part of a larger command that you are splitting into new lines)

You can surround a value with **parentheses** like : **(new command here)**

A working command would look like this :

```
New-ADUser -Name "BoB Glen" -GivenName "BoB"-Surname "Glen" -DisplayName "2003487"`
    -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'pa$$word1' -AsPlainText -Force)`
    -Enabled $true -Path "OU=Public,DC=Company,DC=epl,DC=local"
```

You will notice that the variable **$secpasswd** is removed, the command **ConvertTo-SecureString** is inside **parenthesis ()** the first and last escape characters ` removed, added escape characters to new lines in the command to make it visually more understandable and finally put single quotes around the word **pa$$word** because double quotes will try and read **$** as a variable, while single quotes are read literally.